# Locating an Index, replacing the value and shifting the needed index's down by one

Tags: java, arrays

Hi everyone this is my first time **writing a question** on this website, though I always come here for help regarding my programming assignments. So please excuse any errors or confusions coming from my part.

For this assignment its a "Scoreboard" Themed one. Where we are giving values and we must put those values into an array in order from largest number to smallest number, though also making sure that when a new score is added to the scoreboard if the score is higher than say a score in index[1] the new score goes into index[1] and shifts everything else down by one.

```
name.addscore(43)
name.addscore(30)
name.addscore(35)
name.addscore(50)
name.addscore(31)
```

The above is an example of what scores the user would input randomly, not in order.

So I'm writing a method to addScores onto the array. I need to use 2 loops. The first loop should find and store the index where the new number should go. The second loops should shift the numbers that need to be shifted. Then you can store the new score in the appropriate place.

How do I do the above code in Java?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm sorry I am using Java and my question is basically how to do the last part I mentioned about the loops. I'm new to programing in general so I'm confused. Sorry again for the lack of information

Answer (score 1):

Since you are required to implement this with arrays only and without using 'helper' functions, like those in the Arrays class. You can solve the problem like this:

```
public class ScoreBoard{
    Participant[] participants = new Participant[0];

    public void addParticipant(Participant participant){
        System.out.println("Adding participant: " + participant);

        Participant[] oldParticipants = participants;
        participants = new Participant[oldParticipants.length + 1];

        if(oldParticipants.length == 0){
            participants[0] = participant;
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < oldParticipants.length; i++){
            if(participant.getScore() > oldParticipants[i].getScore()){
                participants[i] = participant;

                for(int j = i; j < oldParticipants.length; j++){
                    participants[j+1] = oldParticipants[j];
                }
                return;
            }

            participants[i] = oldParticipants[i];      
        }

        participants[participants.length-1] = participant;
    }

    public void printScores(){
        System.out.println("\nPrinting current scores...");
        for(int i = 0; i < participants.length; i++){
            System.out.println(participants[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println("Initializing ScoreBoard...\n");
        ScoreBoard sb = new ScoreBoard();

        //Add some participants with scores
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Allen", 37));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Bob", 20));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Mark", 54));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Jenny", 77));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Sue", 32));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Dave", 89));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Jeremy", 26));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Jill", 76));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Sarah", 63));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Don", 92));

        sb.printScores();
    }
}

class Participant implements Comparable<Participant>{
    String name;
    int score = 0;

    public Participant(String n){
        this.name = n;
    }

    public Participant(String n, int s){
        this(n);
        score = s;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return this.score;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + " : " + score;
    }

    public int compareTo(Participant other){
        return -this.score.compareTo(other.score);
    }
}
```

If you are not bound to using arrays and can use any data structure, try this:

```
public class ScoreBoard{
    TreeSet<Participant> participants = new TreeSet<>();

    public void addParticipant(Participant participant){
        participants.add(participant);
    }

    public void printScores(){
        System.out.println("Printing current scores...");
        for(Participant p: participants){
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println("Initializing ScoreBoard...");
        ScoreBoard sb = new ScoreBoard();

        //Add some participants with scores
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Allen", 37));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Bob", 20));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Mark", 54));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Jenny", 77));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Sue", 32));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Dave", 89));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Jeremy", 26));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Jill", 77));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Sarah", 63));
        sb.addParticipant(new Participant("Don", 92));

        sb.printScores();
    }
}

public class Participant implements Comparable<Participant>{
    String name;
    int score = 0;

    public Participant(String n){
        this.name = n;
    }

    public Participant(String n, int s){
        this(n);
        score = s;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return this.score;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + " : " + score;
    }

    public int compareTo(Participant other){
        return -this.score.compareTo(other.score);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to use simple arrays only.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,you are looking for a max heap data structure where root value is the largest value.
You can check this link to get some idea.

http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-max-heap/